# Does "indeterminate" mean "divergent"?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, terminology

Just learning about series and someone tried to tell me that when doing the alternating series test, if the limit is *indeterminate*, it means it is *divergent*, and I wanted to know what exactly the difference between these terms is.  English is not my native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, indeterminate is not the same as divergent. Divergent means that a series, in fact, conclusively diverges.

In terms of "indeterminate": As a synonym, think of "indeterminate" as meaning "*undetermined*": The attempt to *determine*  whether convergent or divergent has failed to provide a conclusive answer; more work needs to be done to *determine* whether it converges, or diverges.

In mathematics, the term used to mean "undetermined" is "*indeterminate*."

Comment: thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

No. If it's indeterminate, then you'll need to find a test that can show if it's either divergent or convergent. Indeterminate means what it sounds like, from whatever test you used, the convergence or divergence cannot be determined.

Comment: Just to double check my understanding: Indeterminate is along the lines of being not known; while divergent means it grows without bounds?

Comment: Yes for the first part. Divergent mean's that the terms do not approach a finite value and or the terms do not tend toward zero. Though there are examples such as the harmonic function, whose terms do go toward zero, but the series diverges.